# Dask dashboard won't connect when creating cluster programatically

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, dask, jupyter-lab, dask-distributed

I have a conda environment with jupyter-lab and dask set up on a google cloud compute engine instance. I have installed the dask jupyter-lab extension so I can see dashboard metrics in the jupyter lab notebook.

I am having no problems running Dask itself, only when connecting the dashboard to a cluster.

This works with no problem when I create a cluster using the dashboard GUI, i.e. clicking on "+New" to create a new cluster. In this case the dashboard usually connects automatically and I can view all of diagnostics/metrics. However, if I create a cluster manually in the code, e.g.

```
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster

cluster = LocalCluster()
client = Client(cluster)
client
```

and then try to connect the dashboard using the provided Dashboard link, I get: `127.0.0.1 refused to connect.` in all of the diagnostic windows. The dashboard options on the left of the jupyter-lab environment do connect however, it is only the diagnostic windows that don't.

Why is this happening? What is the connection difference between creating the cluster using the dask extension UI and creating the cluster programmatically?

Extra info: I am viewing the notebook on my local system via port forwarding, although the kernel is hosted on the virtual machine.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also encountered this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no solution yet.

Comment: I am facing this too. The dashboard runs on localhost:8787, but inside jupyter I get `localhost refused to connect.`

Answer (score 0):

If you have [jupyter-server-proxy](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyter-server-proxy) running, try `proxy/8787`.

`jupyter-server-proxy` lets you run external processes alongside jupyter while letting you access their webservices.  In this case, run `dask` client via `jupyter-server-proxy` to access port `8787`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What is the rationale behind this solution?